# Matlab speech-to-text IBM Watson

Tags: matlab, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

does someone know why my code not working?
I followed the documentation, I did the json file with mt credentials and run this code:

```
    [y,fs] = audioread('example.wav');
    speechObject = speechClient('IBM');
    tableOut = speech2text(speechObject,y,fs);
```

thank you all!

Comment: Does it give you an error? no proper output? How is your code not working?

Comment: Since your code relies on functions that do not ship with MATLAB, the least you should do is provide links to said tools (and documentation). Otherwise, this falls under the category of "cannot be reproduced". I'm assuming [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/65266) is the tool in question.